# eclipse coloring: how to config the background color of folding margin?

Tags: eclipse, colors, preference

I checked every possible editor coloring options carefully, but the background color of folding margin seems not in the preferences dialog. Is it possible to config this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to say, but I don't believe its possible to configure the folding margin color in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open bug on Eclipse's Bugzilla that you can push as well as I am [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=194313)